# Drawer Toggle indicator "hamburger" doesn't animate until after initial orientation change

Tags: android

I've googled this for quite a while and nothing seems to match my issue. When my app starts the hamburger is fixed (no animation) until I do an orientation change, then it animates in both layouts. I'm using the ActionBarDrawerToggle from the v4 support pack (deprecated, I know). Here's the (fairly standard) code:

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.base_activity_fragment);


    //mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // Adding nav items to array
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1))); 
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1))); 
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1))); 
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1))); 
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);

            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }


    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/***
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
/*@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}*/

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer item
 */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment0();
            break;

        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;

        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;

        case 3:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;

        case 4:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            System.exit(1);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager mgr = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = mgr.beginTransaction();
        trans.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        trans.addToBackStack(null);
        trans.commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        /*mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);*/
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the toggle
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav item
        displayView(position);
    }
}
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong and how to get the hamburger to animate all the time? Thanks!

Comment: Ok so it animates when the app is first started and as long as I'm adding new fragments. If I hit the back button the previous fragments will not animate anymore. Is there a specific section and code to put in it to get the animation to work on resumed fragments?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea at all, I'm at a loss here.